# How to display a custom 404-error page in asp.net mvc core

Tags: asp.net, .net, model-view-controller

I am working on ASP.net mvc core 3.1 application where I need to display a friendly page to user if he type wrong url how to redirect my error page. Please help me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shared view of error (Solution Explorer: Pages => Error.cshtml).
For this solution you can add following code in middlewire

```
app.Use(async (Context, next) =>
        {
            try
            {
                await next();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Context.Response.Redirect("/Error");
            }
        });
```